# difference between number in the same column using AWK

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, awk

I have a file containing one column of number:

```
1
2
4
4
10
```

I would like to calculate the difference between each number using awk. The output should be like this :

```
1
2
0
6
```

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try the following code :

```
awk '
    NR == 1{old = $1; next}     # if 1st line 
    {print $1 - old; old = $1}  # else...
' file.txt
1
2
0
6
```

### explanations

- **NR** is the ordinal number of the current record from the start of input.  Inside a BEGIN action the value shall be zero. Inside an END action the value shall be the number of the last record processed.
- **next** statement shall cause all further processing of the current input record to be abandoned. The behavior is undefined if a next statement appears or is  invoked  in  a  BEGIN  or  END
      action.

Comment: if I would like to skip q line each time:
3
2
6

How can I do that ?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo.  
"if I would like to skip 1 line each time: 3 2 6 How can I do that ?"

Comment: I mean that instead of measuringing the difference between two successive lines, I measure the difference between one line and the line after the next one.

Answer (score 21):

Just to make it shorter ...

```
% awk 'NR>1{print $1-p} {p=$1}' file
1
2
0
6
```

Comment: lil more shorter = `awk 'p{print $1-p}{p=$1}' file`

Comment: @JS웃: what if `$1 == 0` ? Are we sure of the numbers are sorted?

Comment: @anishsane Good point. I assumed from OP's data that 0 wasn't a number, but thats a bad assumption.

Answer (score 4):

In case awk is not a strict requirement, a shell solution:

```
set -- $(< file)
p=$1; shift; while (($# > 0)); do echo $(($1 - p)); p=$1; shift; done
```

DRYer

```
set -- $(< file)
while (($#>0)); do [[ -n $p ]] && echo $(($1-p)); p=$1; shift; done
```

Comment: Good solution. However, in my case, I had a file containing a lot of column that's why I thought using awk would be easier.

Answer (score 3):

Code for GNU [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)

```
$awk '{p=f;f=$1} NR>1{print f-p}' file
1
2
0
6
```

Comment: there's nothing specifically gawk-ish about that program.