# Difference between adjacent data rows, with multiple columns

Tags: awk

If I have:

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  .  .
3  4  5  4  2  1  .  .
5  7  5  7  2  0  .  .
.
.
```

I want to show the difference of adjacent data rows, so that it would show:

```
2  2  2  0 -3 -5  .  .
2  3  0  3  0 -1  .  .
.
.
```

I found the post [difference between number in the same column using AWK](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17476879/1983854), and adapting the second answer, I thought that this will do the job:

```
awk 'NR>1{print $0-p} {p=$0}' file
```

But that produces output in and of a single column. How do I get it to retain the column structure of the data?

Comment: the answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112105/awk-pairwise-differences) is what I want, but how do I extend it to arbitrary numbers of columns?

Comment: instead of just linking to another question, let this one stand by itself: what do you want to do?

Comment: @fedorqui  I will rearrange the question so that it is so.

Comment: [edit] your question to get rid of all the `.`s that are making the sample input/output untestable. We need something we can run a potential solution on and diff the output - `...`s in your input/output make that harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR>1 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        printf "%2d%s", $i - p[i], (i<NF ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}
{ split($0,p) }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
 2  2  2  0 -3 -5
 2  3  0  3  0 -1
```

Comment: That works! This was the first time I used awk. I really should start figuring out awk for myself though. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! So I will look at these:
* https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html
* http://www.funtoo.org/Awk_by_Example,_Part_1

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
awk '{for (i=1; i <= NF; i++) { c[i] = $i - c[i] }; count = NF }
     END { for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) { printf c[i] " "}}' numbers
```

Comment: this is giving me one row of zeroes.

Comment: * a row of numbers

Answer (score 0):

Written out:

```
$ cat > subtr.awk
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) b[i]=a[i]
    # for (i in a) b[i]=a[i]
    n=split($0,a)
}
NR > 1 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
    #for(i in a) {
        printf "%s%s", a[i]-b[i], (i==n?ORS:OFS)
    }
delete b
}
```

Test it:

```
$ awk -f subtr.awk file
2 2 2 0 -3 -5
2 3 0 3 0 -1
```

Comment: how do I make this act on multiple rows of data?

Comment: It does. In your example `line1` is subtracted from `line2`. If you feed my solution more lines, let's say 3, `line1` is subtracted from `line2` and that difference is subtracted from `line3`.

Comment: OK, I see that you updated the question. Gimme a minute.

Comment: Oh! I just want the differences of adjacent lines. I'm sorry, the way I put my question initially was unclear. I've modified it accordingly now.

Comment: OK, now it should work if I edited it correctly. I was trying to copy `a` to `b` without `for` using `asorti` but it backfired on me. I need to test that out later.

Comment: Hmm, I have about ten rows and it's fine. Add your data to the question and lets see.

Comment: That's weird, it's probably got something to do with the `for` order and all `for(i in a)` should be replaced with `for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)`. It works fine in my GAWK.

Comment: `for (i in a)` will visit the array elements in the order they were stored in the hash table, not numeric or alphabetic or first in or any useful order. Consider it "random" and as such it MAY produce output in some order you desired/expected given some specific input set but don't trust it always will. To visit in order of numeric indices while still using the `in` operator you can use `for (i=1; i in a; i++)` if the array is contiguous. Note that gawk 4.* has "sorted_in" to allow you to specify the array traversal order using `in`, see the manual.