# awk difference between subsequent lines

Tags: linux, awk

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476879/difference-between-number-in-the-same-column-using-awk) is a great example how to solve the problem if I want to print differences between subsequent lines of a single column.

```
awk 'NR>1{print $1-p} {p=$1}' file
```

But how would I do it if I have multiple (unknown) number of columns in the file and I want the differences for all of them, eg. (note that the number of columns is not necessarily 3, it can be 10 or 15 or more)

```
col1    col2    col3
----    ----    ----
1       3       2
2       4       10
1       9       -3
.       .       .
```

the output would be:

```
col1    col2    col3
----    ----    ----
1       1       8
-1      5       -13
.       .       .
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of saving the first column, save the entire line and you would able to split it then print the difference using a loop:

```
awk 'NR>1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%d ", $i - a[i] ; print ""}
                                          {p=split($0, a)}' file
```

If you need the column title then you can print it using `BEGIN`.

Comment: `print "\n"` will print `"\n" ORS` double-spacing the output, and `split` can be used with two arguments to default to `FS` (`split($0, a)`).

Comment: Just noticed the newline and thanks for the tip about split!

Comment: `print '\n'` exits the single-quotes around the `awk` script, and will print the `awk` variable `n`.  Both `printf "%s", ORS` and `print ""` can be used to print only the `ORS`.

Comment: @kdhp Used print "" now. But it actually worked without this change that I can't explain.

Comment: The `awk` variable `n` was undefined, and was converted to an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'NR<3; NR>3{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%d%s", $i-p[i], (i<NF?OFS:ORS)} {split($0,p)}' file | column -t
col1  col2  col3
----  ----  ----
1     1     8
-1    5     -13
```