# Using sed\awk to display timestamp different between two consequetive lines

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have a log file displays lines like the following:

> 7,5580,70930902,-;2c04000.vdi-ch0: start
> 7,5621,70958680,-;2c04000.vdi-ch0: start
> 7,5662,70986453,-;2c04000.vdi-ch0: start
> 7,5703,71014240,-;2c04000.vdi-ch0: start

the third value after the seconad comma (70930902, 70958680...) is a timestamp. I would like to display at the end of each line  the difeerent between two consequetive timestamps. Can you please help me to figure out how to do that?

I'm a little new with all of the sed\awk stuff, so any detaled answer will be appriciated.

Thanks
Rachel

Comment: Does this answer your question? [difference between number in the same column using AWK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476879/difference-between-number-in-the-same-column-using-awk)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I managed to write a command:

```
awk -F',' '{print NR,$0,"diff = ",a-$3}{a=$3}'
```